# Date minus date query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a query like  below and I want to make calculation for end_scan-packing_date column, how can I achieve this?

```
 SELECT a.invoice_no,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.packing_date,3) as packing_date ,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.exw_date,3) as exw,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.bcd_end_date, 3) as end_date,
       (SELECT TOP 1 insert_date FROM   wms.bcd_shipment d,wms.shinvoicedetails WHERE d.invoice_no = a.invoice_no ORDER  BY insert_date ASC) as start_date ,
       (SELECT TOP 1 insert_date FROM   wms.bcd_shipment d,wms.shinvoicedetails WHERE d.invoice_no = a.invoice_no ORDER  BY insert_date DESC) as end_scan,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, send_date, 3) as swnd_date,customer_short_name,
       Sum(picking_qty) as qty,total_carton
FROM   wms.shinvoicedetails a,
       wms.shinvoiceheder b,
       wms.shinvoice_ctrl c
WHERE  send_date BETWEEN '2014/8/26 00:00:01' AND '2014/9/25 23:59:59'
       AND a.invoice_no = b.invoice_no
       AND a.invoice_no = c.invoice_no
GROUP  BY a.invoice_no,
          b.packing_date,
          b.exw_date,
          b.bcd_end_date,
          send_date,
          customer_short_name,
          total_carton
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Comment: Your SQL code is so messed up I couldn't even reformat it to be readable.

Comment: Code reformatted, please accept.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using` SQL Server?

Comment: could you place a table alias in front of EVERY field please. That way we can trace where the data comes from, at the moment this isn't possible. e.g `SUM(picking_qty)` what table does it come from? don't reply here, edit the query. and I do mean **every** field

Comment: He's asking for `end_scan - packing_date` which are two fields in the select list. That's pretty clear IYAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I refer you to the documentation for the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function (I'm assuming your're using SQL Server as RDBMS).

It has 3 parameters, I am assuming you want the difference in days. So what you want would read something like:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,
         (SELECT TOP 1 insert_date
          FROM   wms.bcd_shipment d,
                 wms.shinvoicedetails
          WHERE  d.invoice_no = a.invoice_no
          ORDER  BY insert_date DESC),
          b.packing_date
) AS diff_days
```

Your query is wrong on many levels though. You are grouping on nearly all columns to get a SUM while you should write that as [a derived table](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/) (a sub-query) grouping only on the necessary fields. Also you are converting to VARCHAR which probably translates to VARCHAR(1). You should probably write it as CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), <your date field>, 3).

Comment: thank you @TT, for your effort this very help me too.

Answer (score 1):

A day does not start at 00:00:01 and does not finish as 23:59:59. Do yourself a favour an don't try to bend your needs to the syntax of `between`. There is an easier and more reliable method

```
WHERE  send_date >= '20140826' AND send_date < '20140926'
```

LESS THAN the 26th; it's more accurate & no silly one second deductions.

> the best practice with date and time ranges is to avoid BETWEEN and to
> always use the form:
>
> WHERE col >= '20120101' AND col < '20120201'
>
> This form works with all
> types and all precisions, regardless of whether the time part is
> applicable.
>
> Itzik Ben-Gan

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-best-practices-part-2

Comment: thank you very much for try to understand and reply my question.

Comment: @ChrisRay no problem, it would help if you added column aliases to every field (absolutely every one!) and what dbms is it for? (could be Sybase or SQL Server I think). "sample data" and "expected result" are almost always very useful

Comment: oic,it's for SQL server . This 1st question from me. I'll try learn about forum rules.thx so much!